# Question title heading outside of design box?

Tags: bug, status-review, design, questions

I am not active member of salesforce but active spam hunter. One of our bot caught [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274548/fdgdrydddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddst) which draw my attention. Long title with out space (In this case it's gibberish) heading out of design box.

[image]

Browser Google Chrome

Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I found this post on mobile, but couldn't delete it until I got to my computer.

Comment: Since this display issue still seems to be occurring, I'll forward this bug report to the relevant developer team.

Answer (score 1):

Please use flags to draw these inappropriate questions to the attention of the moderators.

The referenced post has now been deleted, and I've dealt with a pattern of several question posts that are composed largely or entirely of random characters.

The box overflow isn't something that we can do anything about ourselves.

Comment: Thank's for answer. I aware about flag. Actually I am not familiar with site. Body part hold some information so  I think may be it's reparable.  I read some where on SO meta , bug post on any meta site is track by system. I found bug on salesforce so why I post here.